# jQuery Bootstrap - Empty field validator not working correctly

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a form validator that produces a Bootstrap error/success outline and glyphicon depending on whether or not the field is empty on submit. Currently it works, however the glyphicons are not showing up and the input box does not turn to green once the error has been corrected and the field has been filled in, it only turns green on submit and the user only sees the green outline for a brief second before the page changes. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

HTML:

```
<form id="auth_form" action="action.php" method="post">

  <div class="form-group has-feedback" name="auth_code" id="auth_code">
    <label for="auth_code" class="control-label">Authorisation Code</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="auth_code_input" name="auth_code_input" type="password">
    <span class="form-control-feedback glyphicon"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div>
      <button class="btn btn-info" name="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

jQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

   $('#auth_form').on('submit', function(e) {
     var auth_code = $('#auth_code_input');

     if (!auth_code.val()) {
       auth_code.closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
       auth_code.closest('.form-control-feedback').addClass('glyphicon-remove');
       e.preventDefault();
     } else {
       auth_code.closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
       auth_code.closest('.form-control-feedback').addClass('glyphicon-ok');
     }
   });

 });
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sinesine/xqwsobmo/11/)

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes in your html and js, I think you are looking for something like this:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<form id="auth_form" action="action.php" method="post">

  <div class="form-group has-feedback" name="auth_code" id="auth_code">
    <label for="auth_code" class="control-label">
    <span class='glyphicon' id="iconBad"></span>Authorisation Code</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="auth_code_input" name="auth_code_input" type="password">
    <span class="form-control-feedback glyphicon"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div>
      <button class="btn btn-info" name="submit" type="submit" id="btnSubmit">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

And js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#auth_form").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault()
   }) 
   $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
     var auth_code = $('#auth_code_input').val()

     if (auth_code=="") {
       $('#auth_code').addClass('has-error');
       $('#iconBad').removeClass('glyphicon-ok').addClass('glyphicon-remove');

     } else {
       $('#auth_code').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
       $('#iconBad').removeClass('glyphicon-remove').addClass('glyphicon-ok');
     }
   })
 })
```

Keep in mind you dont need necessarily have a submit button for the form, you can work whitout it too.